# Do you know some def in python how transform a string in a binary code

Tags: python

Im trying to create a function that contains a input where i write a message like "Hi boys"
then my function transform this in a binary code of 1 and 0 (ASCII) i have been trying this :

```
def string_a_binario(s):

    for i in range (0, len(s)):
          if s[i] == "A" :
              return("01000001")   `
```

I need you give a hand fixing my code.

Comment: `format(ord('A'), '08b')` -> `'01000001'`

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s = 'Hi boys'
>>> ''.join('{0:08b}'.format(ord(c)) for c in s)
'01001000011010010010000001100010011011110111100101110011'
```